# How to process data received from an AJAX request in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom hook named "useFetch" which makes an AJAX request and stores the result in the state. I simply want to format the data received from the ajax using a function in my component but not sure how to do this since the function needs to be called only after the data is received.

An example is below:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "../../../Hooks/useFetch";

const Main = () => {
       
    const { data, isPending, error } = useFetch(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/historic/1"
    );
    
    function formatData(data){
        //Do some processing of the data after it's been received
    }

    //This doesn't work of course because it runs before the data has been received
    const formatted_data=formatData(data);

    return (
        //Some display using the formatted data
    );
};

export default Main;
```

This is the custom hook, useFetch, which is used in the above component. I'd prefer to not have to do the formatting in here because the formatting is specifically related to the above component and this custom hook is designed to have more universal utility.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setisPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();

        fetch(url, { signal: abortCont.signal })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw Error("could not fetch data for that resource");
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data);
                setisPending(false);
                setError(null);
            })
            .catch((er) => {
                if (er.name === "AbortError") {
                    console.log("fetch aborted");
                } else {
                    setError(er.message);
                    setisPending(false);
                }
            });

        return () => abortCont.abort();
    }, [url]);

    return { data, isPending, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Perhaps creating selectors would do the trick for you. While Reselect was written for redux, it can be used with plain js as well. It'll give you the benefit of memoizing the data as well. https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap it with useEffect hook with data as it's deps.

```
const [formattedData, setFormattedData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  if (!data) return;

  const _formattedData = formatData(data);

  setFormattedData(_formattedData);
}, [data]);
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for thanks